# How do I get a JS function resut to a HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, random

I'm trying to build an app in js that would get a random question from an array that would combine with a random object from another array. So my app looks like this:

```
Array.prototype.random = function (length) {
    return this[Math.floor(Math.random()*length)];
};

var country = [
    {name:"Romania", capital: "Bucuresti"},
    {name: "Bulgariei", capital: "Sofia"}
];

chosen_country = country.random(country.length);

var questions = [
    "Which is the capital of ",
    " is the capital of which country?"
];

var chosen_question = questions.random(questions.length);

function q() {
    chosen_country;
    chosen_question;
    if(chosen_question == questions[0]) {
        return chosen_question + chosen_country.name + "?";
    } else if(chosen_question == questions[1]) {
        return chosen_country.capital + chosen_question;
    }
}

q();
```

So my app will generate a random question from the questions array and combine it with a random object from the country array:

1. "Which is the capital of 'country x' ?"
2. "'Capital x' is the capital of which country?"

I would like to know how get the random question generated with a button form in HTML. Afterwords I would like to answer the question within an input form and send the answer to be use in another function to check if the answer is corector not. Anyone having any idea?

I have tried to use `document.getElementById("que").innerHTML = q();` but I realy don't know how to use it properly. Is there any other solution or I could use some explanations how to use `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Unrelated, but passing the length of an array in to an array prototype function seems weird.

Comment: Can we see your HTML?  If `que` is an input, you should use `value` instead of `innerHTML`:  `document.getElementById("que").value = q();`

Comment: her is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/quac22ho/

Comment: Just a general good practice: don't extend native constructs.  There are too many reasons why (google it), but you should just create a helper object with methods you can call (similar to how underscore works).

Comment: @RyanWheale Extending the Array prototype (or other built-ins) isn't *that* harmful. There even is an entire library that does that (http://sugarjs.com/).

Comment: I'm not going to start a debate, but sugar does it "right", per se, unlike the OP (re. enumeration, etc).  And even if he does it "right", is he aware that it could cause problems in IE8?  That he might break another libraries code?  That he might propagate the confusion about what's real and what's not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a different way of setting up the whole thing. You might find some of the ideas useful.

- no library (pure DOM interaction)
- more question possibilities than just country and capital
- a simple string formatter for building the question text

```js
Array.prototype.random = function () {
    return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)];
};
String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
function randomQuestion(bundle) {
    var fact = bundle.facts.random(),
        question = bundle.questions.random();

    return {
        text: question.text.replace(/\{([^}]+)\}/, function($0, $1) {
            return fact[$1];
        }),
        answer: fact[question.compare]
    };
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
var countryBundle = {
    facts: [
        {country: "Romania", capital: "Bucuresti", continent: "Europe"},
        {country: "Bulgaria", capital: "Sofia", continent: "Europe"},
        {country: "Germany", capital: "Berlin", continent: "Europe"},
        {country: "France", capital: "Paris", continent: "Europe"},
        {country: "India", capital: "Delhi", continent: "Asia"}
    ],
    questions: [
        {text: "Which is the capital of {country}?", compare: 'capital'},
        {text: "{capital} is the capital of which country?", compare: 'country'},
        {text: "On what continent lies {country}?", compare: 'continent'}
    ]
};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
function setupForm() {
    var questionLabel = document.getElementById("question"),
        answerInput = document.getElementById("answer"),            
        currentQuestion,
        showNextQuestion = function () {
            currentQuestion = randomQuestion(countryBundle);
            questionLabel.textContent = currentQuestion.text;
            answerInput.value = "";
        };

    showNextQuestion();
    document.getElementById("nextQuestion").onclick = showNextQuestion;
    document.getElementById("enter").onclick = function () {
        var correctAnswer = currentQuestion.answer.trim().toLowerCase(),
            givenAnswer = answerInput.value.trim().toLowerCase();

        if (correctAnswer === givenAnswer) {
           alert("Yes :)");
           showNextQuestion();
        } else {
           alert("No :(");
        }
    };
}

setupForm();
```

```html
<button id="nextQuestion">Next question</button><br>
<label for="answer" id="question">&nbsp;</label><br>
<input id="answer">
<button id="enter">OK</button>
```

Comment: WoW! nice code you got there! :) This is exactly what I wanted to build myself. It's kinda hard to unterstand some parts of the code as long I'm kinda novice in js. I don't realy know much about regex and I think I should learn some stuff about it... I love your aproch with regex and the countryBundle object I think that it's amazing :D I don't get it how the randomQuestion(bundle) function generates the random question, but i can get it on fly, i guess.... Now I kinda want to build another method by myself cuz practice makes the best, I think it will take a while for me to do this,

Comment: Thank you. Well, I could explain how `randomQuestion()` works, exactly, but I will be more useful in terms of learning if you find out yourself. Open the browser's developer tools, set a few breakpoints and step through the code. It's not that difficult to figure out how it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've changed your code a bit.  I'm using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector), which is more powerful than `getElementById`, but you'll need to use a pound sign (#) when referring to elements with Ids.

I've also moved your click handler from the HTML into the JavaScript, which is best practice.

Each time you click the button, `que` will show a random question:

```js
Array.prototype.random = function (length) {
  return this[Math.floor(Math.random()*length)];
};

var country = [
      {name:"romaniei", capital: "bucuresti"},
      {name: "bulgariei", capital: "sofia"}
    ],
    questions = [
      "What is the capital of ",
      " is the capital of what country?"
    ]

document.querySelector('input').onclick= function() {
  var q,
      chosen_country = country.random(country.length),
      chosen_question = questions.random(questions.length);
  
  if(chosen_question == questions[0]){
    q= chosen_question + chosen_country.name + "?";
  } else if(chosen_question == questions[1]){
    q=  chosen_country.capital + chosen_question;
  }
    
  document.querySelector('#que').innerHTML= q;
}
```

```html
<form name="myform">
  <input type="button" value="Generate question">
  <div id="que">Intrebare:</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Nice!! that is what i was looking for. That's greate, thanks... but wher was my mistake? and how dose querySelector actualy works?

Comment: `getElementById` can reference elements with IDs only.  `querySelector` can reference all elements, the same way CSS does.  W3Schools has some good examples:  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

Comment: There were a few things:  1. Your Fiddle wasn't doing anything with the result of the `q` function.  2. The input element was referring to an unknown `q2` function.  3. jsFiddle doesn't work well with inline events, which is another reason to define them in the script section.